# How to create variables in a loop in Python

Tags: python

how would I be able to make something like this that actually works?

```
choices = input('Enter choices. ')

i = 0
while i < 10:
    number_of_{}s.format(i) = choices.count(str([i]))
    i += 1
```

Comment: For a normal case, use a `dict` or `list`. For this case, [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "actually works".  Clarify, please.  Check the posting guidelines for ... well, guidelines.  :-)

Comment: If you're trying to create a bunch of related variables, we give them a single name and use a sequence (tuple, list) or collection (set, dictionary) of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tools the language gave you for this problem. Use lists.

```
i = 0
number_of = []
while i < 10:
    number_of.append(choices.count(str([i])))
    i += 1
```

Even better, use `for`.

```
number_of = []
for i in range(10): number_of.append(choices.count(str([i])))
```

Or, best, a list comprehension.

```
number_of = [choices.count(str([i])) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @gb0ffi lol I Just stopped a second doing PHP to answer this. See now